pybind11 cross compilation can link against native python executable, can't install cross python
Working on x64 ubuntu22.04 and on ubuntu23.10 with python3.10 and python3.11 on both.
I can build my project natively for both python versions, controlling the python version using PYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION - which then triggers find_package(Python3 ${PYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION} REQUIRED EXACT COMPONENTS Interpreter Development), or by passing directly PYTHON_EXECUTABLE.
However, trying to build this project for aarch64 (using a toolchain for aarch64, see at the bottom), fails.
I can make it build and run, if I manually set the PYTHON_EXECUTABLE to my native PYTHON_EXECUTABLE. I don't understand how and why...
What I expected to do was:

install an aarch64 python (lib, headers, executable) on my machine
use find_package(Python3 ${PYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION} REQUIRED EXACT COMPONENTS Interpreter Development) or better yet DPYBIND11_FINDPYTHON=ON (as can be seen here)

I can't install the cross python3 [step (1)], no matter what I tried... Is this the correct method to go about cross compilation? or should I really use x64 python executable for aarch64 build?
# toolchain file
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)                                                                                                                                                            
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                          
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)                                                                                                                                             
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)                                                                                                                                           
set(CMAKE_STRIP aarch64-linux-gnu-strip CACHE FILEPATH "Strip")  


Presumably it uses the Python executable to run some Python code during the build? In which case an aarch64 binary won't execute much on an x64 machine. On the other hand, the libraries are to be linked with your C++ binary, so they need to match the target arch.

If they are using the exec during build time - it doesn't make sense to ask for a cross exec - since it won't be able to run. On the other hand, it doesn't make sense to me to ask for the native one - as running a native exec on a cross lib is also very weird... Having the lib and headers obviosuly is required - but I had issues installing only them as well (done that by mounting a arm64 docker container... doesn't feel right 2 me)
